# Getting 500 Internal Server Error with jQuery AJAX and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to submit a form (it's a dynamic form with fields added via jQuery) to CodeIgniter for a db insert. Part of it works, the other part doesn't.

**Here's the jQuery:**

```
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/raffle/save/',
        data: $('#raffle').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Failed'); // This is what I get unless I comment out the entry insert
        }
    });
}
```

**The CI controller:**

```
class Raffle extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('raffle_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['title'] = 'Create a Raffle';
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('raffles/create_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('raffles/bottombar_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer', $data);
    }

    public function save() {
        foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
            if($k == 'entrant' || $k == 'tickets') {
                foreach ($v as $i => $vector) {
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('entrant[' . $i . ']', 'Entrant name', 'trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[100]|xss_clean');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tickets[' . $i . ']', 'Number of tickets', 'trim|required|max_length[2]|is_natural_no_zero|xss_clean');
                }
            } else {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('raffle-name', 'Raffle name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[100]|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('winners', 'Number of winners', 'trim|required|max_length[2]|is_natural_no_zero|xss_clean');
            }
        }

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            echo 'Validation failure!';
        } else {
            if($this->raffle_model->add_raffle()) { // It does pass validation and goes to the model
                echo 'Data added successfully!';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the **CI model:**

```
class Raffle_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function add_raffle() {
        // This works
        $meta = array(
            'user_id'    => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'name'       => $this->input->post('raffle-name'),
            'winners'    => $this->input->post('winners'),
            'created_ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        );

        // This works and is a multidimensional array for insert_batch()
        $entrants = array(
            array(
                'date'      => date(DATE_ATOM),
                'raffle_id' => '1'
            )
        );

        foreach($_POST['entrant'] as $name => $n) {
            array_push($entrants,
                array(
                    'name'    => $n,
                    'tickets' => $_POST['tickets'][$name]
                )
            );
        }

        $this->db->insert('raffle', $meta);
        $this->db->insert_batch('entry', $entrants); // This one returns error 500

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Here's the problem:** Submitting the form, the `meta` portion does get saved to the `raffle` table, but the `entrants` portion does not get saved to the `entry` table. I have tried using a simple dummy array (sample data, no post data, no loops) to see if it would work, but it still doesn't. Console logs say `POST http://rafflegrab.dev/raffle/save/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

CSRF is off in CI config.

The table is set up as follows:

1. Table name: entry
2. InnoDB
3. id - bigint(12) - UNSIGNED - not_null - AUTO_INCREMENT - PRIMARY
4. user_id - int(10) - UNSIGNED
5. name - varchar(100)
6. tickets - smallint(5) - UNSIGNED
7. date - datetime
8. raffle_id - int(10) - UNSIGNED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using unsafe input methods to be able to access $_POST ?

What happens if you mock up a noddy form with those fields and post it to the `Save` action on the controller?

Next question is the usual stuff but what do the server logs say? Have a look in the Event Log (windows) or `/var/log/apache2/error_log` (SUSE) or the equivalent on your system. It should tell you why it's not working.

If not, make sure your php log level is high enough to output errors.

If you're not in a production environment, consider [displaying PHP errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) until you've tracked down the problem

Edit: Always better to know the problem than guess but my first thought is that your 2-dimensional array as inconsistent. You seem to have:

```
array(
    array('date'=>blah, 'raffleId'=>blah),
    array('name'=>blah, 'tickets'=>blah),
    array('name'=>blah, 'tickets'=>blah)
    ...
)
```

Did you in fact want

```
array(
    array('date'=>blah, 'raffleId'=>blah, 'name'=>blah, 'tickets'=>blah),
    array('date'=>blah, 'raffleId'=>blah, 'name'=>blah, 'tickets'=>blah),
    array('date'=>blah, 'raffleId'=>blah, 'name'=>blah, 'tickets'=>blah),
    ...
)
```

? Perhaps something like:

```
    $entrants = array();
    $recordedDate = date(DATE_ATOM);
    foreach($_POST['entrant'] as $name => $n) {
        array_push($entrants,
            array(
                'date'      => $recordedDate,
                'raffle_id' => '1'
                'name'    => $n,
                'tickets' => $_POST['tickets'][$name]
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! PHP.ini is set to `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On`. I have the error log file saved, and there are no errors in it (I previously cleared a bunch of older ones out, so it's working). From what I gather, CI will return a 500 error if the database returns an error, which I suspect the issue to be, but unsure as to why. I have tried making a dummy array for the insert statement, which contained no POST data, and changing `insert_batch` to `insert`, and the result is the same.

Comment: In CI's database config file, make sure debug is set to `True` (actually, I have mine set to `(ENVIRONMENT=='Development')` but you get the gist.

Comment: np - That Edit was made before I saw your comment. Now you're not batch inserting, I'm not sure if it still applies but let's see

Comment: Ok, tried: `$entrants = array( 'name' => 'Me', 'tickets' => 2, 'date' => date(DATE_ATOM), 'raffle_id' => '1' ); $this->db->insert('entry', $entrants);` - same 500 error :(

Comment: Hmm. Ok, without an error message this is going to be tricky. You could try using the [profiler](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html) which _may_ give you some output before dying. Alternatively, examine the connection using Wireshark or similar to see what's actually being executed and track it down.

Comment: Fixed! It had something to do with how the table was setup - I had to delete the table and recreate it after an obviously unsuccessful attempt at trying to create relationships via foreign keys (I suspect these were the issue). I still had to apply part of your answer to get it working without a dummy array (I needed to be pushing the date and raffle_id along with each entry), so I'm going to accept your answer, and thanks again!